# Is "quarrel with somebody over something" natural-sounding English?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, idiomatic-language

I'm talking about my disagreement with my pal, Ha.

Could you tell me if the use of quarrel in this sentence is natural-sounding?

> I quarrelled with my best buddy, Ha, over which dining establishment we should go to for dinner.

Comment: _Fining establishment_? if you mean _dining_, I would call it a restaurant. Have you looked up _to quarrel_ in a dictionary?

Comment: It's perfect English! I love the way this expression uses 'over' as if they were quarrelling over a point (or 'bone') of contention lying on the ground (or table, I suppose) between them! You're using it perfectly.

Comment: The "to for", as WendyG says, is probably overkill. it should be "where we should go for dinner " or "where we should go to dinner".

Answer (score 1):

> "I quarrelled with"

is perfect, the end of the sentence is not.

"which dining establishment" has never been said seriously, it may have been said by somebody parodying posh people.
You would say restaurant, pub, cafe etc, or if you didn't care what sort of place you ate at, you would simply say "where"

> over which restaurant we should go to for dinner.
> over where we should go <s>to</s> for dinner.

note **to** is removed when you are saying where. I don't know why, but I suspect like lots of these oddities it is because it doesn't really flow when spoken.

Comment: How do you know Liz isn't parodying posh people? I assumed that's precisely what she was doing!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, native speakers would use the expression as in your example sentence.

However, hearing one say that would give me an indication of the relative age of the speaker.  The younger generations would typically say "argue" in place of "quarrel."  "Quarrel" would be more often used by the Baby Boomer generation or in rather formal speech.

Comment: yes I am Gen X, and it is quite formal, for the 'best buddy' that follows it.

Comment: I think _dining establishment_ would be an even clearer indication of the speaker's age :)